# Overlapping Circles

Tags: html, css, styles, overlapping

I need your help to overlap circles to be similar to the sample of overlapping circles as it is shown in the process section at the below link :

https://rudo.studio/

```css
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 9%;
}
```

```html
<div ID="process" class="process">
     
      <div style="circleProcess">
       
        <span ID="cricle1" class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle2"class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle3"class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle4"class="dot"></span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin `margin: 9% -15px 0;` on `.dot`

```css
.process{
  padding:0 15px;
}
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9% -15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div ID="process" class="process">
     
      <div style="circleProcess">
       
        <span ID="cricle1" class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle2"class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle3"class="dot"></span>
        <span ID="cricle4"class="dot"></span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add negative value in `.dot` class `margin:9% -15px 0` and also add css  `transform:scale(1.05)` on hover of div to get hover effect

```css
.process {
  padding: 0 25px;
}
.dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 9% -15px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.dot:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div ID="process" class="process">
  <div style="circleProcess">
    <span ID="cricle1" class="dot"></span>
    <span ID="cricle2"class="dot"></span>
    <span ID="cricle3"class="dot"></span>
    <span ID="cricle4"class="dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks:) you helped me